# How to set a class to a <v-data-table> column with Vuetify?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

How to set a class to a column with Vuetify data table ?

I have tried to set it in the `template`, but it's not taken into account:

```
<template v-slot:item.code="{ item }" class="primary">
  {{ item.code }}
</template>
```

I also tried to set it from the `headers` property, but only the header cell is set:

```
headers: [
  {value: "code", class:['primary']},
  {...}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<template v-slot:item.code="{ item }">
<div class="primary">
{{ item.code }}
</div>
  
</template>
```

Comment: `<div>{{ item.code }}</div>` would be acceptable, but if you check the html code, here you are setting a `<td>` in a `<td>`.

Comment: yes , you have different options for what you want to put inside the template and set your class on it .